# Oracle output results of query to file

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

Currently i am running multiple queries which spool the output to a file this can be a lengthy process, below are my current settings in sqlplus.

```
set feedback off
set heading off
set echo off
set termout OFF
set linesize 150
set long 1999999
set longchunk 1999999
set pagesize 0
spool results.sql
@queries.sql
spool off
set termout on
set echo on
set heading on
set feedback on
```

I was wondering if there is any way i can speed up this process? Or is there a faster way of sending output of the queries to a file using sqlplus?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably not the outputting of the results that is the problem but the queries being performed. You would need to improve the performance of the SQL.

Comment: @Ciarán i'm running very simple select queries e.g.`Select id,name,address from person;` that is as complicated the queries get.

Comment: You can try to increase the arraysize to something like 500. If the bottleneck is the network from the database to your client, it'll speed up a bit.

Comment: Is the SQLPLUS client on the server or not?

Answer (score 1):

## Clarifications

Can you please clarify the following

1. Is the **sqlplus** client on the same physical box (or virtual machine) that your database management system is on (more specifically, your `ora` and `datafiles`)?
2. Can you test your query by decreasing the size of the result set using `fetch first n rows`?

## Time Complexity and Specifics

Why do you believe the bottleneck is spooling?  Before jumping to any conclusions about the causes of poor performance you may want to try an gather some timing statistics on your query.  I would modify your query to only return a subset of rows

```
SELECT * FROM scott.dept FETCH FIRST 10000 rows
```

Optimizing your queries is highly depending on how your data is structure and how your routines run, so in order to optimize you need to be able to benchmark your performance changes.

You will then want to check the following two parameters

```
SHOW PARAMETER statistics_level
SHOW PARAMETER timed_statistics
```

And you will also want to time your queries

```
SET TIMING ON
```

> Remember, all of this is simply to benchmark performance, you will need to revert these settings in production.

Keep in mind that running the same query multiple times will cause inconsistent performance metrics because of pooling / buffering / caching / etc.  You should query the `v$statistics_level` and investigate

- Rows Processed
- Sort (memory)
- Sort (Disk)
- physical reads
- consistent get

I would `SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATELY; STARTUP MOUNT;` and then your an explain on your query multiple times.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM SCOTT.DEPT;
```

Check if the explain plan is changing on your subsequent calls.

Additionally, in certain circumstances you can force a cache of a table by running

```
SELECT * FROM SCOTT.DEPT CACHE;
```

And then comparing it to the performance metrics of

```
SELECT * FROM SCOTT.DEPT NOCACHE;
```

You may want to also keep the table in-memory indefinitely

```
ALTER TABLE *scott.dept* STORAGE (buffer_pool keep)
```

If you don't see anything glaring then run an  `explain plan for` your query.  Run the explain multiple times in succession to see if anything changes.

Beyond that, you should also remember that running your query multiple times without flushing your buffers / clearing cache is going to give you unreliable readings.  If you aren't sure the spooling is the bottle neck, I would also suggest you run an `explain plan for your` query

There are also some tricks to increasing performance over time (assuming this routine is ran regularly).  If you with `alter table *table_name* cache`, run the query without spooling to a file, then running again `alter table *table_name* nocache` with spool you may be a more performant run, but again if this is feasible completely depends on your use cases.

## Settings

While I doubt your issue here is going to be solved by any combination of settings, below are a few that may provide marginal benefits

1. `set trimspool on`

> Removing white spaces in spool file to fill up linesize
> 2. set echo off
> This may be pointless depending on whether your routine is fully automated or interactive
> 3. `set verify off`
> This will remove substitution variables from your spool, but can speed up your process considerably... again, depending on your data
> 4. `set autoprint off`
> This is another variable setting.  Off is the default setting, but you but assurance I would explicitly set it
> 5. `set serveroutput off`
> 6. `SET TRIMOUT ON`
> Removes whitespaces filling linesize on out file
> 7.  `set arraysize N`
> You are definitely going to tinker with this one.  N is the number of rows being fetched at a single time.  The size of this depends on the structure of your table

While these settings *may* increase the speed of your routines, performance is generally specific to your architecture and data set.